# Stabilizing videos with moving objects

Tags: opencv, video, video-processing

I'm trying to stabilize a video taken at a beach, which contains ocean waves, rocks, beach, mountains, and etc.

Detecting key points and warpPerspective based on the displacement of each point does not work well, because the key points contain moving objects such as waves and people.

The expected results are as if the camera position and the angle were fixed all the time; The only moving objects in the video are waves, people, birds, and etc.

Is there any suggested way of achieving this? Maybe Detecting only the non-moving objects? Non-moving objects may move in the video because of the camera angle, this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward method is to use "phase correlation" between adjacent frames:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_correlation

It'll give you relative displacement between each pair of adjacent frames, provided that most content is the same. OpenCV has a convenient function called `phaseCorrelate(...)` that uses this algorithm specifically:

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#phasecorrelate

Have a look and see if it fits your purpose. Other image registration algorithms may also work, but phase correlation is likely to be the fastest for large enough images.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I just tried phase correction but it does not seem to be working on the video which most of its regions are moving waves. Is this as expected?

Comment: Hm... If most of the image is moving, you'll have a hard time registering the image with any image registration algorithm. Not sure what you could do with that. The information to compute the proper shift between the frames just isn't in the frames any more.